# Where is data stored in RAM vs. Instructions stored in RAM?

Tags: cpu, ram

So, I have had this question, recently I have been learning more and more about lower level computer things like opcodes and how computers read binary.

But I have come across a question I simply couldn't find a good answer to.
This is, as the title explains:

In RAM where is the data stored vs. where the instructions for the program stored in RAM?

Are the instructions even stored in RAM? I've heard of ROM, but I don't know what this is. I'm confused, if the cpu fetches everything from the registers and the RAM, where would the instructions for what happens be?

Any answers would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/faculty/wolfe/book/Readings/Reading04.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data and instructions are all stored together in the same memory. It's the context of how it's accessed that makes the difference.

This concept of computer architecture goes all the way back to at least 1945: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture